# PHPExcel copy Worksheet without fx

Tags: php, formula, phpexcel

I'm working on a PHPExcel based application and i need to copy a entire Worksheet from a Workbook to another, without copying the FX but only Values.

Some ideas?

Comment: Copy, right click Paste Special -> Values? Or how are you wanting to automate this?

Comment: @franglais Nope, is a Web Application based on [link](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)

Comment: Hah, ok. Was just checking :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve only the data :

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("myworkbook.xlsx");
```

Or you can get the calculated values of cells :

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A2")->getCalculatedValue();
```